# Как наклонить карточку, при наведении курсора на угол?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Как сделать наклон карточки, при наведении указателя мыши на угол карточки?

Например, как здесь - http://www.matter-of-mind.fr/en/talents/contact

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется этот эффект, и есть ли готовый код на **codepen.io** ?

Comment: Думаю на этом сайте вы найдёте себе решение вашего вопроса:
[Кликабельно](https://css-tricks.com/animate-a-container-on-mouse-over-using-perspective-and-transform/)

Comment: Следят за положением курсора над блоком и меняют значения:
transform: rotateX() rotateY();

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/WNbYBLr

Answer (score 4):

Чаще всего, этот эффект называют - **Parallax Tilt Effect**

Код небольшой и понятный (примеры лучше смотреть развернув страницу):

```js
const cards = [...document.querySelectorAll(".card")];

cards.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("mousemove", fCardRotate);
  el.addEventListener("mouseout", fCardDefault);
});

function fCardRotate(ev) {
  this.style.transform = `perspective(2000px) rotatey(${(ev.offsetX - this.offsetWidth / 2) / 6}deg) rotatex(${((ev.offsetY - this.offsetHeight / 2) / 6) * -1}deg)`;
}
function fCardDefault() {
  this.style.transform = ``;
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  transform: perspective(2000px) rotatey(0deg) rotatex(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

---

Если добавить оформление:

```js
const cards = [...document.querySelectorAll(".card")];

cards.forEach(el => { el.addEventListener("mousemove", fCardRotate); el.addEventListener("mouseout", fCardDefault); });

function fCardRotate(ev) { this.style.transform = `perspective(2000px) rotatey(${(ev.offsetX - this.offsetWidth / 2) / 5}deg) rotatex(${((ev.offsetY - this.offsetHeight / 2) / 5) * -1}deg)`; }
function fCardDefault() { this.style.transform = ``; }
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 1500px #90a4ae;
  font: bold 6vh "Arial";
  color: #c0c0c0;
  text-shadow: -1px -2px 5px #000a, 1px 2px 3px #fff;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  transform: perspective(2000px) rotatey(0deg) rotatex(0deg);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in 1.5s;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 4px 6px -1px white, inset -0px -3px 7px -2px black, inset 1px 2px 1000px grey, 5px 25px 45px -20px black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.card:hover {
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="card">Parallax</div><div class="card">Tilt</div><div class="card">Cards</div></div>
```

Ну и в сети много примеров. Один из них - https://codepen.io/AbubakerSaeed/pen/rNNdvqz