# Наклон текста относительно мыши

Tags: javascript, css

Как реализовать наклон текста относительно мыши, как [здесь](https://acrode.com/)
У меня скрипт такой

```
var $text = $('.text'),
  w = $(window).width(), //window width
  h = $(window).height(); //window height

$(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var offsetX = 0.5 - e.pageX / w,
    offsetY = 0.5 - e.pageY / h,
    transform = 'rotateX(' + (-offsetY) + 'deg) rotateY(' + (offsetX * 2) + 'deg)';

  $text.css('transform', transform);
});
```

Мне он он не нравится, так как ярко не выражена трансформация

Comment: Добавьте ваш код, укажите в чём возникло затруднение.

Comment: что уж там - давайте по пунктам - `как изготовлена каждая секция на этом сайте` - в принудительном отпуске за +10 в карму всё напишут :))

Comment: цветочек меня не интересует. А вообще здесь много чего интересно сделано, чего трудно найти в Интернете качественно сделанного

Comment: если ввести в гугле "наклон текста относильно мыши js css", то первой ссылкой будет мой вопрос здесь. Думаю вопрос актуальный

Comment: а если написать в codepen.io - 3D mousemove - то появляются результаты: https://codepen.io/kyiv/pen/MKdBMa

Comment: https://codepen.io/JanneLeppanen/pen/KwBbGK - а тут вообще меню сделано на 3d поворотах на js

Comment: спасибо, там не искал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запускаем, открываем на весь экран, водим курсором и радуемся:

```js
const wrap = document.querySelector(".txt");

function fCardRotate(ev) {
  wrap.style.transform = `perspective(2000px) rotatey(${(ev.offsetX - wrap.offsetWidth / 2) / 10}deg) rotatex(${((ev.offsetY - wrap.offsetHeight / 2) / 10) * -1}deg)`;
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", fCardRotate);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.txt {
  transform: perspective(2000px) rotatey(0deg) rotatex(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  font: bold 7vh/1em 'Arial';
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">
  <p>Нужно пытаться, что-то делать самому.</p>
  <p>Прилагать хотя бы минимальные усилия.</p>
  <p>Тогда и результат будет обязательно.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, у меня не так смотрелось ярко, потому что перспективу не устанавливал

Comment: Даже на телефоне робит... + в репу

Comment: @helldrg: но с "яркость" перебарщивать не стоит, пощадите людей - цветные прыгающие штуки в больших количествах быстро утомляют.

Comment: @helldrg: карточки по тому же принципу - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1094910/265406

Comment: не ярко, а точнее натурально, не было ощущения, что текст вращается

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: @helldrg: перспектива, тени и градиенты - основа реализма

Comment: здесь кст неравномерно вверх вниз вращается текст

Comment: @helldrg : всё верно. На сайте-образце тоже непропорционально, но из-за малой амплитуды, это не так заметно. Ну и я же не вижу вашей вёрстки и следовательно мой ответ, только как образец, а "допиливать" нужно "по месту".